# Creating a marker proportionally offset along a line in QGIS 2.4 when re-projecting

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, markers, qgis-2.4

One of the nice new features in QGIS 2.4 is to be able to offset markers (e.g. arrow heads) along a line as part of the styling. I am trying to display a dataset of simple lines (not polylines) with an arrowhead 90% of the way along the line. My attempted method is as follows:

Layer Properties -> Style -> Symbol -> Change...

- Select "Marker Line"
- Marker placement: on first vertex only
- Offset along line: Map Unit
- Data Defined Properties...

  - Offset along line = $length * 0.9

This works fine when my layer projection was the same as for the project (all EPSG:27700 - OSGB 1936 / British National Grid). However, now that I have added an OpenStreetMap basemap layer, it seems that can't be re-projected so I have to switch my project CRS to that of OpenStreetMap (EPSG:3857 WGS 84 / Pseudo Mercator). Putting in a "fiddle factor of" 1.6 seems to do the trick ($length * 0.9 * 1.6), but that's a bit of an unpleasant hack. Better solutions?